# Join results of subqueries in Django

Tags: python, django, join, subquery

I'm implementing a distributed event store using [Vector Clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) to establish a deterministic ordering of events.

I'm attempting to perform the following raw query using Django ORM:

```
   SELECT dev_snapshots.global_snapshot_id as snapshot_id, 
          dev_snapshots.environment_id, 
          dev_snapshots.clock,
          test_snapshots.environment_id,
          test_snapshots.clock
   FROM (
          SELECT
            global_snapshot_id,
            clock,
            environment_id
          FROM environment_snapshot
          WHERE environment_id = 'dev') dev_snapshots
     JOIN (
            SELECT
              global_snapshot_id,
              clock,
              environment_id
            FROM environment_snapshot
            WHERE environment_id = 'test') test_snapshots
       ON dev.global_snapshot_id = test.global_snapshot_id
   ORDER BY dev_snapshots.clock, test_snapshots.clock
```

My models are as follows:

```
class Environment(models.Model):
    env_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    current_clock = models.BigIntegerField()


class EnvironmentSnapshot(models.Model):
    global_snapshot = models.ForeignKey('GlobalSnapshot')
    environment = models.ForeignKey('Environment')
    clock = models.BigIntegerField()


class GlobalSnapshot(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

`Environment` has a name and a counter value called `clock`.
`EnvironmentSnapshot` is a snapshot of a single `Environment`'s clock value during a single `GlobalSnapshot`.
`GlobalSnapshot` collects `EnvironmentSnapshot`s for all environments that exist at the time the `GlobalSnapshot` is created.

The idea is to sort all the `GlobalSnapshot`s first by the clock value of the "dev" `Environment`, then by the clock value of the "test" `Environment` to get a deterministic order of events regardless of when the event was received. `GlobalSnapshot` is eventually joined to an event that is recorded in the event store.

I've looked into `Query.join()` in Django but it doesn't seem very well documented, or even meant for end users to use.

Is there a way for Django ORM to do this, or will I simply need to construct a raw query for Django to execute?